# change worksheet after msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a specific worksheet after hitting 'ok' on a msgbox. So, if I run a loop in 'sheet1', a msgbox would appear and say 'found x records' and after hitting 'ok', 'sheet2' would open. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Sample()     
'Your Loop    
Msgbox "Loop Finished!" & vbcrlf & "Found x records"    
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sheets("Sheet2").Activate is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Msgboxes are modal, and code execution will stop while they are open and they also return a value (depending on the button pressed)

The example below puts the response of the message box into `response` and then uses an if to run the code depending on the response.

```
Sub Main()
Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult

' Do Processing stuff here

Response = MsgBox(Prompt:="Prompt!", Buttons:=vbOKCancel, Title:="Title!")

If Response = vbOK Then
    ' Do stuff for OK
Else
    ' Do nothing or something else
End If

End Sub
```

The `If` is optional, if you dont care what button is pressed you can just put all your code after the call to `msgbox()` and it will be executed when the message box is closed.